# Matlab run section doesn't work

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing

I have two sections in Matlab separated with %% but the run section command still produce the error that all function definitions should be at the end of the file, how can I solve this ? my code is the following:

```
%%1
close all;
clc

imgFilename = 'image1.png'

%loading the image
img = my_loadImage(imgFilename);

%convert to double floating point
img = im2double(img);

%showing the image
my_showImage(img);

%convert to grey
imgGray = rgb2gray(img);
imshow(imgGray);


%solution
function [img] = my_loadImage(X)
img = imread(X);
end

function [] = my_showImage(X)
imshow(X);
end


%%2
close all;
clc

%splitting the RGB channels of the color image
[imgR, imgG, imgB] = my_RGBSplit(img);

%solution
function [imgR, imgG, imgB] = my_RGBSplit(X)
imgR = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
imgG = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
imgB = rgbImage(:, :, 3);
end
```

I'm using Matlab r2017b.

Comment: Make those functions as nested functions, and all each of the sections as a function without inputs and outputs: `function x` at the beginning of the section and `end` at the end of each section.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, all function definitions have to be at the end of the file. You have code in between your function definitions, this isn't allowed.

Comment: yeah but the section feature should run every section as if it was an independent program, ignoring other sections

Comment: No, it won't run them as if they're independent programs because that's not how MATLAB is designed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add a space between the `%%` and the name of the cell:

```
%% 1
close all;
clc
```

and

```
%% 2
close all;
clc
```

Then, be sure you activated the cell mode, by going in Cell > Activate Cell Mode. You will have access to a tab where you can choose which cell to evaluate.

[image: cell mode]

**Once you clicked on your editor**, on the top menu you should see **Cell**, then once you ckicked on it, **Enable Cell Mode**.

Here is a video to [Mathworks Blogs](https://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/07/26/starting-in-matlab-cell-mode-scripts/) that explains how it works.

---

EDIT, Update for Matlab 2017b.

In **Home** > Preferences > Editor/Debugger > Autoformatting > Section break, be sure you checked:

> %%, ***, or --- for section break
>      %% text for section break and heading

[image: matlab]

Then, in **Editor** you will see various options to execute the different sections of your code:

> Run Section
>   Advance
>   Run and Advance

[image: matlab editor]

Comment: ok i added the space, doesn't seem to solve the problem. Where can i find Activate Cell Mode in Matlab r2017b ?

Comment: Edit: ok but Matlab R2017b doesn't even look like this .. it has no top menu.

Comment: @anisgh, this [link](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections.html) explains how to do it in 2017b.

Comment: Upvoting for effort!

Comment: I have 2017a and I see a greyed out button for "Run section".  I've read and implemented everything above and haven't been able to fix it.